# Issue with helm helpers iterating over an array of maps

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm having a few issues when trying to use helms range function when trying to iterate over a array of maps.

values.yaml - Example

```yaml
global:
  envVars:
    externalSecret:
      - name: SECRET_NAME_1
        gcpSecret: SECRET_KEY_1
      - name: SECRET_NAME_2
        gcpSecret: SECRET_KEY_2
```

The helm helper i've put together was this:

```yaml
{{- define "chart.envVars.externalSecret" -}}
{{- range $externalSecret := .Values.global.envVars.externalSecret -}}
- name: {{ .name }}
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ include "chart.fullname" $ }}
      key: {{ .gcpSecret | replace "_" " " | lower | camelcase }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

What I am expecting this to output out is:

```yaml
- name: SECRET_NAME_1
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: chart-fullname
      key: SecretName1
- name: SECRET_NAME_2
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: chart-fullname
      key: SecretName2
```

However all I am getting are these errors through the `helm lint`

```bash
templates/deployment.yaml: unable to parse YAML: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Within the deployment.yaml, all I am doing is calling the defined variable like so:

```yaml
env:
  {{- include "chart.envVarsFull" . | nindent 12 }}
```

I have tried multiple methods of trying to iterate over this list but I can seem to get past the error stating mapping is not allowed.

Examples of things tried but still failing

- [Helm iterating over array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72382139/helm-iterating-over-array-of-objects?rq=2)

Does anyone smarter than me have a way to do that? :D

Cheers!

Comment: Does it work to remove the hyphen either at the end of the `range` line, or at the start of the first `end` line?  `helm template --debug .` will print out the invalid YAML and it might be helpful to see in context what's gone wrong.

Comment: @DavidMaze cheers for the response. Just tried removing the `-` at the end of the `range` line, but sadly still the same. I also ran with `--debug` and it mentions:

```
Error: YAML parse error on chart/templates/external-secret.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 22: mapping values are not allowed in this context
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 22: mapping values are not allowed in this context
YAML parse error on chart/templates/external-secret.yaml
```

Which sadly just still points to issues with ranging over those values

Answer (score 1):

turns out that yes I am an idiot! The syntax actually works, I was looking at the wrong area of my helper that was throwing errors. Just for reference, the following yaml helper does indeed work as expected:

```yaml
{{- define "chart.envVars.externalSecret" -}}
{{- range $externalSecret := .Values.global.envVars.externalSecret }}
- name: {{ .name }}
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ include "chart.fullname" $ }}
      key: {{ .gcpSecret | replace "_" " " | lower | camelcase }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```